# shorewall configuration for allowing chromecast

Tags: chromecast, shorewall

I am having difficulty setting up chromecast on my local network.  The chromecast device is successfully connected to my network, but reports it cannot access the Internet.  That is not true, because I see that it successfully resolved google's servers and is communicating over HTTPS.  I also see that multicast is working such that my tablet is able to connect to it.

My router is running shorewall 5 (which is essentially an iptables wrapper).  And, for wireless, I'm running hostapd, I don't have AP isolation enabled (the default setting in hostapd).

I ran tcpdump, but didn't see anything being blocked other than I am rejecting google's DNS for my own.

Is there something I'm missing, why can't the device access the "Internet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. reject all outbound UDP traffic to DNS and NTP ports
2. redirect outbound UDP NTP traffic to my NTP server
3. chromecast will fallback to the DHCP provided values (I have both a DNS and NTP server locally)

Well, this is both disappointing and excitingly simple.  The disappointing part is the lack of documentation, some open source projects are much more thoroughly documented than this beast.  And for the excitingly simple part, well, the chromecast requires both NTP and DNS to function (DNS is obvious, NTP less so).  If your dropping packets to the NTP and DNS servers google desires to use, then you're out of luck.  You simply need to change the ruleset on your router to reject those packets instead of silently dropping them and it should just work.  Additionally, it appears it is also required to redirect UDP NTP traffic to your NTP server.  Simply rejecting it isn't enough.

A wiki page from the engineers at google would be great.